# CampaignTrackingReceiver is not registered for Campaign Measurement - Android SDK v4

Tags: android, android-intent, google-analytics

Please find the below code for more information.

```
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService"
            android:enabled="true"/>
```

This is what I have done for implementing Campaign Measurement - Android SDK v4. 
In order to check is it working or not, when I try to run this on terminal:

> adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n
>   "com.example.android/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
>   --es referrer "utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"

it successfully cast an intent

> Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER
>   cmp=com.example.android/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver
>   (has extras) } Broadcast completed: result=0

and when I run my application I get the log as follows:

CampaignTrackingReceiver is not registered, not exported or is disabled. Installation campaign tracking is not possible. See http://goo.gl/8Rd3yj for instructions.

I had tried many example but not got the sufficient result. Anyone if knows the whole working then please provide me a link or if anybody knows the exact steps plz list them.

Thanxx in advance

Comment: Have you mentioned analytics service in your manifest file?

Comment: got any solutions??